# How to download text from many webpages to file?

Tags: linux, bash, console, lynx

I'm trying to download a polish dictionary. Unfortunately, the [existing files](https://sjp.pl/slownik/growy/) contain all inflections (not sure what the proper english word is). I found out that the command

```
lynx --dump https://sjp.pl/slownik/lp.phtml?f_vl=2&page=1 > file.txt
```

can download a single dictionary webpage. I would then have to somehow extract only the dictionary entries from the block of text, but at least it's a start.

Unfortunately, I'm a linux noob and don't know how I can iterate through all the 3067 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you should be able to do it quite fast and easily with **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel -qk 'lynx --dump https://sjp.pl/slownik/lp.phtml?f_vl=2&page={}' ::: {1..3067} > file.txt
```

If it doesn't work, try removing the single quotes. If that doesn't work, try putting a backslash before the `&`. Sorry, I don't have any way to test at the moment.

The slow way is:

```
for ((i=1;i<3068;i++)) ; do
   lynx --dump ...page=$i
done > file.txt
```

Comment: I've found out that using `lynx ... page=$i` only shows the first page no matter the `i`, which I don't understand, because `https://...page=i` definitely links to the i-th page.

Comment: actually, so do other programs, such as curl or wget. Using `wget https://sjp.pl/slownik/lp.phtml?f_vl=2&page=200` will get the content of `...page=1`, while pasting `...page=200` does show the 200-th page... I don't understand.

Comment: ok, I found out that I had to put the link in quotes, because lynx was misinterpreting the "&"

Comment: Please have another look at the answer as Ole has kindly added the `-q` option to look after the quoting for us.